# Instagram media ID to timestamp conversion

Tags: go, time, instagram, unix-timestamp, date-conversion

Instagram explains how they create their media ID in this blog post

https://instagram-engineering.com/sharding-ids-at-instagram-1cf5a71e5a5c

> Each of our IDs consists of: 41 bits for time in milliseconds (gives
> us 41 years of IDs with a custom epoch) 13 bits that represent the
> logical shard ID 10 bits that represent an auto-incrementing sequence,
> modulus 1024. This means we can generate 1024 IDs, per shard, per
> millisecond.

> our ‘epoch’ begins on January 1st, 2011
> not sure if that's the actual production value or only for the example

How can I get the timestamp back from a media ID?

I have this two media ids where I know the timestamp, but I need to extract it from others

`2384288897814875714 2020-08-26T13:43:27Z`

`2383568809444681765 2020-08-25T13:52:46Z`

Comment: What have you tried and what did not work out?

Comment: I've just managed to re-create the same media id.. at least the timestamp part I guess.. because the beginning looks the same.. but I've no clue to reverse it, because lack of deeper understanding of bits flipping stuff https://play.golang.org/p/VdCs81meoGN

Comment: To get the 41 most significant bits shift 64-41=23 bits to the right: `ts := id >> 23`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ZNEp-pMav_I)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

const (
    instaEpoch int64 = 1314220021721
    mediaID int64 = 2384288897814875714
)

func main()  {
    extractedTimestamp := mediaID >> (64-41)
    timeFromMediaID := extractedTimestamp + instaEpoch
    fmt.Println(time.Unix(timeFromMediaID/1000,0).UTC())
}
```

Output:

```
2020-08-26 13:43:27 +0000 UTC
```

You can just right shift the id to get the timestamp back. Then you have to add the miliseconds to the epoch instagram is using.